# SQL - Query Running Very Slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have table relations like below :

[image: Table Relations Via phpmyadmin]

I run the following query from php and ran in two big problems. 

1) The maximum memory limit exceeded
2) The maximum execution time exceeded

```
SELECT DISTINCT venues.name, locations.location, events.event, types.type, foods.food, beverages.beverage, event_options.event_option, styles.style, space_requirements.space_requirement, features.feature

FROM (SELECT * FROM venues v LIMIT $offset,$limit) venues

INNER JOIN locations ON venues.location_id = locations.location_id

LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venues.venue_id = venue_events.venue_id
LEFT JOIN events ON events.event_id = venue_events.event_id

LEFT JOIN venue_types ON venues.venue_id = venue_types.venue_id
LEFT JOIN types ON types.type_id = venue_types.type_id

LEFT JOIN venue_foods ON venues.venue_id = venue_foods.venue_id
LEFT JOIN foods ON foods.food_id = venue_foods.food_id

LEFT JOIN venue_beverages ON venues.venue_id = venue_beverages.venue_id
LEFT JOIN beverages ON beverages.beverage_id = venue_beverages.beverage_id

LEFT JOIN venue_event_options ON venues.venue_id = venue_event_options.venue_id
LEFT JOIN event_options ON event_options.event_option_id = venue_event_options.event_option_id

LEFT JOIN venue_styles ON venues.venue_id = venue_styles.venue_id
LEFT JOIN styles ON styles.style_id = venue_styles.style_id

LEFT JOIN venue_space_requirements ON venues.venue_id = venue_space_requirements.venue_id
LEFT JOIN space_requirements ON space_requirements.space_requirement_id = venue_space_requirements.space_requirement_id

LEFT JOIN venue_features ON venues.venue_id = venue_features.venue_id
LEFT JOIN features ON features.feature_id = venue_features.feature_id
```

I am using this query to retrieve all the accessories related to each venue. I need to implement pagination in backend so I am using LIMIT $offset,$limit in Sub Query. I could not found any other idea (query) so I could achieve the same result that I am retrieving now. Currently I am using

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` 
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);`

php functions to ignore those problems, but I think this is not the best practice. Also I am thinking for the condition when I may have to retrieve all the accessories of 50+ venues, for which `max_execution_time = 60` may not be sufficient.

How can I get rid of this problem? 
Please Help Me.

**Updated** 
The number of rows fetched is (events * types * foods * beverages * event_options * styles * space_requirements * features) each venue have. But the number of rows useful to me is not the multiplication but the sum.

And Here is the result I found after running my query with the `EXPLAIN` keyword

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => 
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => 
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 11
            [Extra] => Using temporary
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_events
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 3
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => events
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_events.event_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_types
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 7
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => types
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_types.type_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_foods
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 3
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => foods
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_foods.food_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_beverages
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 3
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => beverages
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_beverages.beverage_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_event_options
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 2
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => event_options
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_event_options.event_option_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_styles
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => styles
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_styles.style_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_space_requirements
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 3
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => space_requirements
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_space_requirements.space_requirement_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => locations
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => venues.location_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => venue_features
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 4
            [ref] => venues.venue_id
            [rows] => 7
            [Extra] => Using index
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [table] => features
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY
            [key] => PRIMARY
            [key_len] => 1
            [ref] => serofero_mvb.venue_features.feature_id
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [select_type] => DERIVED
            [table] => venues
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => 
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 11
            [Extra] => 
        )

)
```

Thankyou

Comment: You are probably missing indexes. Run the query directly with the `EXPLAIN` keyword. Provide the result here.

Comment: I have never used indexes so I was unknown about it's power. And thankyou for introducing the `EXPLAIN` keyword, I will google how to use that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any time you are joining two columns together, each column should have the same matching data type and both columns should be indexed. It will allow mysql to sort and match the rows much faster.

Comment: But there is still the same problem after adding indexes.

Answer (score 2):

create indexes for columns you selected.

Comment: Ok thankyou. Should I create index for all the tables that are`JOINED` in above query ?

Comment: I created index in all tables, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to the following;

```
SELECT DISTINCT venues.`name`, locations.`location`, events.`event`, types.`type`, foods.`food`, beverages.`beverage`, event_options.`event_option`, styles.`style`, space_requirements.`space_requirement`, features.`feature`
```

Keep in mind that this is just first line of the code. you need to change this everywhere in your query.

Reason because of you getting this error is that indexes are missing and in this way indexes will be defined in proper way and will be easy for php to distinct.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the EXPLAIN output, it seems like the query is already using the PRIMARY KEY as the index. Why don't you try splitting the query.

First, get the ids of the venues that you want to display (paginated).

```
SELECT id FROM venues v LIMIT $offset,$limit

$venue_ids = implode(',', $results);
```

Next, run this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT venues.name, locations.location, events.event, types.type, foods.food, beverages.beverage, event_options.event_option, styles.style, space_requirements.space_requirement, features.feature

FROM venues

INNER JOIN locations ON venues.location_id = locations.location_id

LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venues.venue_id = venue_events.venue_id
LEFT JOIN events ON events.event_id = venue_events.event_id

LEFT JOIN venue_types ON venues.venue_id = venue_types.venue_id
LEFT JOIN types ON types.type_id = venue_types.type_id

LEFT JOIN venue_foods ON venues.venue_id = venue_foods.venue_id
LEFT JOIN foods ON foods.food_id = venue_foods.food_id

LEFT JOIN venue_beverages ON venues.venue_id = venue_beverages.venue_id
LEFT JOIN beverages ON beverages.beverage_id = venue_beverages.beverage_id

LEFT JOIN venue_event_options ON venues.venue_id = venue_event_options.venue_id
LEFT JOIN event_options ON event_options.event_option_id = venue_event_options.event_option_id

LEFT JOIN venue_styles ON venues.venue_id = venue_styles.venue_id
LEFT JOIN styles ON styles.style_id = venue_styles.style_id

LEFT JOIN venue_space_requirements ON venues.venue_id = venue_space_requirements.venue_id
LEFT JOIN space_requirements ON space_requirements.space_requirement_id = venue_space_requirements.space_requirement_id

LEFT JOIN venue_features ON venues.venue_id = venue_features.venue_id
LEFT JOIN features ON features.feature_id = venue_features.feature_id

WHERE venues.id IN ( $venue_ids )
```

That should at least get rid of the derived table.

Comment: Thankyou for your response , but still It takes lots of time. The maximum memory limit is exceeded, and same about execution time. Can ob_start() and ob_flush() be helpful for this situation. It is 1:13 AM (Nepal) and I can't sleep because of it. There are 52575 rows fetched, I am afraid. Is it normal??

Comment: So you have like 10 venues to begin with because it's paginated right?  How did you end up with 50k rows?

Comment: Because each venue can have multiple events, types so on and so forth. The mysql results me exponential of that as 5 (events) * 25 (types) * 15 (foods) and I am helpless.